# Are the following functions probability densities on the intervals given - is my solution correct?

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function

I don't have answers to refer to, so could please someone check if the way I solved this problem is correct? I have an exam tomorrow and want to make sure that I've got it right. THank you in advance!

Check whether the following functions are probability densities on the corresponding sample space Ω = I:

(a) $f(x) = 1/x, I = [1, e]$, where e = exp(1)

> $f(x)>0$ for all x on the $I= [1, e]$
>
> $\int^e_11/xdx=lne-ln1=1$ so it
> is a PDF.

(b) $f(x) = exp(x/3)$, $I = [0, 1]$

> $f(x)>0$ for all x on $I = [0, 1]$
>
> $\int^1_0e^{x/3}=\int^1_0x/3lne=[x^2/6]^{x=1}_{x=0}=1/6 - 0=1/6$ so
> **NOT** a pdf

(c) $f(x) = x/4, I = [−1, 3]$

> $x/4>0 -> x \not=0$ or any negative number but the interval [-1,3] contains 0 and negative numbers--> f(x) is
> **NOT** a pdf

Comment: (a) seems correct. But check $\int e^{x / 3} \, dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) looks correct.

(b) You want to check that again. The anti-derivative of $e^{x/3}$ is $3e^{x/3}$.

(c) $\frac{x}{4} > 0$ does not imply $x > 4$. But you are right that the function is not positive.

EDIT: Ok, you noticed (c) yourself. Good.

Comment: Thank you @Klaus, much appreciated! :)